Electric field experienced by a charge
We have two charges, say $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.
The magnitude of the electric field $E$ experienced by charge $Q_2$ is:
$$E = \frac{k Q_1}{r^2}$$
where $k$ is Coulomb's constant and $r$ is the distance between the two charges.
The force $F$ done on charge $Q_2$ by the electric field is:
$$F = E . Q_2$$
My question concerns the equation of the electric field. We know that both charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ possess electric field, so how can we be sure that the equation above expresses the real magnitude because in reality even charge $Q_2$ produces an electric field.

The equation most definitely does not express the "real" magnitude of the field, it is meant to be only the field caused by $Q_1$. The field caused by $Q_2$ has no net effect on $Q_2$ itself so it can be left out.

but before the electric field has an effect on the charge, the field caused by the charge itself will not interact with it?

The fields just add up and do not influence each other. EM fields are linear, fields with nonlinear field equations would indeed give more complicated behavior (like the color field between quarks).

If you will, the charge interacts with its own field by causing that field.

@JosBergervoet could you elaborate how the color field between quarks are nonlinear, please? It looks like that the QCD Lagrangian consisted entirely of summation terms; summation over fermion colors, summation over fermion flavors, summation of gluon potentials, summation over coordinate dimensions... Where does the non-linearity comes from in strong interaction?

@James In QCD the gluon field has color charge, so the field creates an additional field, which makes it nonlinear. The QCD Lagrangian [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics#Lagrangian] has terms that are cubic and quartic in the gluon field $A^a_\mu$, because the field strength tensor $G^a_{\mu\nu}$ contains a quadratic term $g f^{abc} A^b_\mu A^c_\nu$. If we use Euler-Lagrange to derive field equations for the color-electric field from it, they will be similar to the Maxwell equations but there will be nonlinear (quadratic and cubic) terms in it.

What we measure (with a load cell for example) is the force on charge 2. And we can test that $F \propto \frac{Q_1Q_2}{r^2}$.
Then we define the electric field in the location where $Q_2$ are as: $E = \frac{F}{Q_2}$
The electric field in any other location have the contribution of both charges.

But the field of $Q_2$ not only exists at other locations, also inside and outside $Q_2$ itself (which might be a spherical charge distribution for instance). Still we leave it out, because it does not create any force on $Q_2$ itself. But it still exists! Actually, inside  $Q_2$ and close to $Q_2$ the self-field of  $Q_2$ is much stronger than the field of  $Q_1$, but still we can ignore it. (We do not have to ignore it of course, but then the formula $$E = \frac{k Q_1}{r^2}$$ in OP's question would become different.)

Thank you good people for the answer and comment. If the force $F$ is proportional to the charge $Q_2$, it means that the charge is applying force on itself?

When dealing with that type of situations, I assume point charges. It is the same approach for mechanics with forces and movements of particles, where the concepts are clear. Real finite elastic bodies requires of course continuous mechanics. In the same way, finite charged bodies requires distribution of forces (and fields) in the bodies.

@user134613 No. But the force on it depends on its charge. As the gravitational force on a body depends on its mass.

Ok, thank you ! :-)
